# Error with label while Proc export in excel sas

Tags: sas

I have some data set. (name - table, field - Field1 label="current.field")
When I do

```
proc export data=work.table label;
outfile = 'bla bla';
DBMS=Excelcs;
run;
```

I get an error:

```
CLI execute error: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel 
       Driver] 'current.field' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include 
       invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long..
```

I know that the problem is in label - it contains ".". But I need this label fro my need. Do anyone knows how to solve this problem? Than you.

Comment: This is actually a Microsoft Excel question and not a SAS question.

Comment: @DomPazz Ok. But is it possible to export into second row of Excel? I will prepare Excel template with these labels in the first row. Do you have an example? range is not supported((

Comment: Your code is not valid SAS syntax. I can't test it right now but I don't see why the period as a label would throw an error. Make sure your code works without label first and then try and modify it. What version of SAS are you using?

Comment: @Reeza code is working without label. I checked) 9.2

Comment: You don't need a semicolon after word label.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do in SAS, is to modify those labels so that they will play nicely with the Excel driver.  The following `xl_label()` macro will scan your table and remove any periods (.) from your labels.

```
/* sample data */
data work.table;
  label x ='test1.invalid' y='test2.invalid';
  x=1; y='age';
run;

%macro xl_label(lib=,ds=);
  /* get labels */
  ods output variables=vars(keep=variable label); 
  proc contents data=&lib..ds; run;

  data _null_; set vars;
    /* modify labels to make them valid for excel */
    label=tranwrd(label,'.','_');
    /* send to macro variable array */
    call symputx(cats('label',_n_)
      ,"label "!!variable!!'="'!!label!!'";'
      ,'l');
  run;

  /* update table metadata */
  proc datasets nolist library=&lib;
    modify &ds;
  %local x;
  %let x=1;
  %do %while (%symexist(label&x));
    &&label&x /* label statements */
    %let x=%eval(&x+1);
  %end;
%mend;

%xl_label(lib=work, ds=table);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need these labeles with "." Is it possible to paste data set  into excel from  second row of sheet?

Comment: I've added another answer, one that uses a web query as opposed to excel driver.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your SAS labels with periods (.) in Excel (row 2) you can try the approach outlined in this [blog post](http://rawsas.blogspot.co.uk/2016/11/sas-as-service-easy-way-to-get-sas-into.html).

Simply add the label keyword to the proc export step as follows:

```
/* send data */
PROC EXPORT DATA=&libds OUTFILE=_webout DBMS=&type REPLACE LABEL; 
run;
```

Then, when setting up the web query, ensure your target is a cell in row 2 (eg A2).  This worked fine for me, as follows:
[image: example excel results]